# Where is the User's information stored when they are create via ACL SETUSER in Redis?

Tags: redis

When I create a new user in redis using the acl setuser command, like the following:

```
acl setuser ankit on >generalpassword +@all -@dangerous ~*
```

Where is this information about the new user stored?
I checked the redis.conf file.
Is it stored in another file? If yes, which file is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ACL database is stored in memory (RAM) and get lost if you restart Redis. To persist it to disk, you need to invoke the [`ACL SAVE`](https://redis.io/commands/acl-save/) command:

> When Redis is configured to use an ACL file (with the aclfile
> configuration option), this command will save the currently defined
> ACLs from the server memory to the ACL file.